# install pyinstaller on solaris8

Tags: python, solaris, pyinstaller

I'm using solaris-8 in sunblade-150 with python-2.5

"uname -a" outout:

```
SunOS xxxx 5.8 Generic_108528-20 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Blade-100
```

and python version as:

```
Python 2.5 (r25:51908, Sep 20 2006, 06:18:53) 
[GCC 3.4.6] on sunos5
```

I'm trying to install pyinstaller-2.1 and from pyinstaller documents I found that I have to build the boot-loader with:

```
python ./waf configure build install
```

The output of the above command goes well:

```
SunOS-32bit detected 
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/local/bin/gcc 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/local/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/ccs/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/ccs/bin/ranlib 
Checking for gcc                         : ok  
Checking for library dl                  : yes 
Checking for library z                   : yes 
Checking for function readlink           : yes 
Checking for flags -m32                  : yes 
'configure' finished successfully (4.084s)
Waf: Entering directory '/home/local/user/vs750/home/ad_temp/pyinst/PyInstaller-2.1/bootloader/build'
[ 1/40] cc: common/pyi_utils.c -> build/debug/common/pyi_utils_1.o
[ 2/40] cc: common/pyi_launch.c -> build/debug/common/pyi_launch_1.o
[ 3/40] cc: common/pyi_pythonlib.c -> build/debug/common/pyi_pythonlib_1.o
[ 4/40] cc: common/pyi_archive.c -> build/debug/common/pyi_archive_1.o
[ 5/40] cc: common/pyi_python.c -> build/debug/common/pyi_python_1.o
[ 6/40] cc: common/pyi_global.c -> build/debug/common/pyi_global_1.o
[ 7/40] cc: common/main.c -> build/debug/common/main_1.o
[ 8/40] cc: common/pyi_path.c -> build/debug/common/pyi_path_1.o
[ 9/40] cc: linux/getpath.c -> build/debug/linux/getpath_1.o
[10/40] cc: common/pyi_utils.c -> build/release/common/pyi_utils_2.o
[11/40] cc: common/pyi_launch.c -> build/release/common/pyi_launch_2.o
[12/40] cc: common/pyi_pythonlib.c -> build/release/common/pyi_pythonlib_2.o
[13/40] cc: common/pyi_archive.c -> build/release/common/pyi_archive_2.o
[14/40] cc: common/pyi_python.c -> build/release/common/pyi_python_2.o
[15/40] cc: common/pyi_global.c -> build/release/common/pyi_global_2.o
[16/40] cc: common/main.c -> build/release/common/main_2.o
[17/40] cc: common/pyi_path.c -> build/release/common/pyi_path_2.o
[18/40] cc: linux/getpath.c -> build/release/linux/getpath_2.o
[19/40] cc: common/pyi_utils.c -> build/releasew/common/pyi_utils_3.o
[20/40] cc: common/pyi_launch.c -> build/releasew/common/pyi_launch_3.o
[21/40] cc: common/pyi_pythonlib.c -> build/releasew/common/pyi_pythonlib_3.o
[22/40] cc: common/pyi_archive.c -> build/releasew/common/pyi_archive_3.o
[23/40] cc: common/pyi_python.c -> build/releasew/common/pyi_python_3.o
[24/40] cc: common/pyi_global.c -> build/releasew/common/pyi_global_3.o
[25/40] cc: common/main.c -> build/releasew/common/main_3.o
[26/40] cc: common/pyi_path.c -> build/releasew/common/pyi_path_3.o
[27/40] cc: linux/getpath.c -> build/releasew/linux/getpath_3.o
[28/40] cc: common/pyi_utils.c -> build/debugw/common/pyi_utils_4.o
[29/40] cc: common/pyi_launch.c -> build/debugw/common/pyi_launch_4.o
[30/40] cc: common/pyi_pythonlib.c -> build/debugw/common/pyi_pythonlib_4.o
[31/40] cc: common/pyi_archive.c -> build/debugw/common/pyi_archive_4.o
[32/40] cc: common/pyi_python.c -> build/debugw/common/pyi_python_4.o
[33/40] cc: common/pyi_global.c -> build/debugw/common/pyi_global_4.o
[34/40] cc: common/main.c -> build/debugw/common/main_4.o
[35/40] cc: common/pyi_path.c -> build/debugw/common/pyi_path_4.o
[36/40] cc: linux/getpath.c -> build/debugw/linux/getpath_4.o`
```

until it gets an error as follows:

```
[37/40] cc_link: build/debug/common/pyi_utils_1.o build/debug/common/pyi_launch_1.o
build/debug/common/pyi_pythonlib_1.o build/debug/common/pyi_archive_1.o           build/debug/common/pyi_python_1.o
build/debug/common/pyi_global_1.o build/debug/common/main_1.o           build/debug/common/pyi_path_1.o 
     build/debug/linux/getpath_1.o -> build/debug/run_d

Undefined           first referenced
  symbol                in file
setenv                 debug/common/pyi_utils_1.o
unsetenv               debug/common/pyi_utils_1.o

ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to
/home/local/user/vs750/home/ad_temp/pyinst/PyInstaller-2.1/bootloader/build/debug/run_d
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Waf: Leaving directory      '/home/local/user/vs750/home/ad_temp/pyinst/PyInstaller2.1/bootloader/build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): 
    {task: cc_link pyi_utils_1.o,pyi_launch_1.o,pyi_pythonlib_1.o,pyi_archive_1.o,pyi_python_1.o,pyi_global_1.o,main_1.o,pyi_path_1.o,getpath_1.o -> run_d}`
```

As you may see, there is an error message about undefined symbol for: "setenv" and "unsetenv".

I want to know how can I proceed the installation process and solve the problem. I'm really eager to have pyinstaller on my Solaris and therefore, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Look like it can't find `/home/local/user/vs750/home/ad_temp/pyinst/PyInstaller-2.1/bootloader/build/debug/run_d` You can also install it by `sudo easy_install pyinstaller`

Comment: Actually it dose not look for /home/.../run_d but it tries to write into that. When there are errors in advance, there would be no output.    
I have no Internet connection on the box, so I believe I could not use easy_install. Anyway I have no experience with that and so good if you could help me more in that regard.

Comment: Sorry it's out of my field :/

Comment: @adaf Can you please tell me how you got python-2.5 compiled on solaris 8? I'm trying to compile it for two days now.